# List all tabs of richfaces TabPanel that has validation error

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I have a `rich:tabpanel` with several tabs which contains some inputs in each tab. The tabpanel has `switchType="client"` tag attribute value. There is also a submit button(commandButton) that submit the form.

I want to show a message on the top of the webpage that list all tabs which input caused a validation error. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`<rich:popupPanel>`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=modalPopup) (as modal panel) to show your desired messages by using `<h:messages>` inside. Validate all your inputs and if one has errors then add a new message, in the `<oncomplete>` javascript method of your `<a4j:commandButton>` show the popup panel to notify the user about the operation results.